# discord python bot leave command not working

Tags: python, audio, discord, discord.py

Below is the code used for the join and leave command.
Join works fine but leave does not. Tried many solutions on stackoverflow but none worked.

````
@commands.command(name='join')
  async def join(self, ctx):
    print('join command worked')
    member = utils.find(lambda m: m.id == ctx.author.id, ctx.guild.members)
    if member is not None and member.voice is not None:
      vc = member.voice.channel
      player = self.bot.music.player_manager.create(ctx.guild.id, endpoint=str(ctx.guild.region))
      if not player.is_connected:
        player.store('channel', ctx.channel.id)
        await self.connect_to(ctx.guild.id, str(vc.id))```

  
@commands.command(pass_context=True)
  async def leave(ctx):
      if (ctx.guild.voice_client):
          await ctx.guild.voice_client.disconnect()
          await message.channel.send('Bot has left')
      else:
          await ctx.channel.send("I'm not in a voice channel, use join command to add me.")```

Any possible solutions?
Thanks
````

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the variable `message` doesn't exist in the current scope: using just `ctx.send("Bot has left")` should work fine for your purposes.